# Selenium Finding elements in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get value **View View** ?

```
<tr class="">
    <td class=" _100u">
        <label class="_55sg _kv1">
            <input name="select_single_row_checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="100010456172450">
                <span class="_66ul"></span>
        </label>
    </td>
        <td class=" _100u">
            <div direction="left" class="clearfix">
                <div class="_ohe lfloat">
                    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100010456172450/picture?width=32&amp;height=32&amp;access_token=2712477385668128|b429aeb53369951d411e1cae8e810640" class="img _8o _8r img" alt="">
                </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="_42ef _8u">
                            <div>
                                <a data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=100010456172450" class="_3cb8" href="/100010456172450">View View</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </td>
            <td class=" _100u">
                <abbr aria-label="3 weeks ago" class="livetimestamp" data-utime="1606705616">11/30/20</abbr>
            </td>
</tr>
```

I try write the code below but not return result anything and program remain running

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3cb8']").getAttribute("href")
    print(a.text)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3cb8"))) 

for a in elements
    print(a.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Why are you getting attribute href? Just remove that

Comment: Thank for your response.I try remove attribute href but not print anything and program remain running

Comment: First assign , driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3cb8']") to a variable and then print the variable and see if any element is being detected add a sleep before that

Comment: I write the code below the result was the same It .Looks like the program is stuck on line 2.                                                                                   
1.driver.implicitly_wait(5000)                                                                                   
2.data_page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3cb8']")
3.print("data_page",data_page)

Comment: Use explicit wait presence of all elements located by

Comment: Can you advise me? I tried code like this still can't work.                                      
line 1 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3cb8")))
line 2 data_page = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='_3cb8']")                   
line 3 print("data_page",data_page)

Comment: Updated the answer could you try the updated answer

Comment: I use this code you update not work.no return result anything and program remain running.Could it be that about the web site policy?

Comment: If this also doesn't work check if the tag is inside iframe